# How to set a capacity for Distributed Schem in Coherence Cache

Tags: oracle-coherence, capacity

I setup a  in my configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE cache-config SYSTEM "cache-config.dtd">

<cache-config>
   <caching-scheme-mapping>   
         <cache-mapping>
              <cache-name>DIST_CACHE</cache-name>
              <scheme-name>distributed</scheme-name>
         </cache-mapping>     
   </caching-scheme-mapping>

   <caching-schemes>         

            <distributed-scheme>
                <scheme-name>distributed</sceme-name>
            <backing-map-scheme>
                <local-scheme>
                    <high-units>1000</high-units>
                    <unit-calculator>FIXED</unit-calculator>
                    <eviction-policy>LRU</eviction-policy>
                </local-scheme>
                </backing-map-scheme>

            <autostart>true</autostart>
            </distributed-scheme>
   </caching-schemes>

</cache-config>
```

As fas as I understand I shouldn't be allowed to put more than 1000 entries in my cache and since I am running it on my local machine there are no other resource and 1000 is a hard limit.

However I am able to do it :

```
NamedCache cache = CacheFactory.getCache("DIST_CACHE");                

try{            

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( new FileInputStream("testFile.txt")));    
    String line = "";
    String strKey = "";
    while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
        System.out.println("Key : " + newkey);
        strKey = newkey+"";
        cache.put(strKey,line);
        newkey++;              

        System.out.println("Number of elements in the Cache : " + cache.size());                     
    }
}        

catch(Exception ex1){
    System.out.println("Last line loaded : " + newkey);
    System.out.println("Exception : " + ex1);
}
```

My testFile.txt contains about a million of records and I am easily surpassing 1000 entries threshold. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

The High-Unit denotes the value after which Coherence Caches will start evicting data using LRU policy to accommodate new incoming entries, just to make sure that you don't run out of memory. So i am not sure whether you were expecting an out of memory exception from your code or not? because in ideal scenario you won't get it; As coherence must have deleted entries from your cache to make room.

Second thing to keep in mind is that the High unit is applicable per cache per instance i.e. each coherence server that you are running can accommodate 1000 entries for that particular NamedCache. So if you are running 2 cache server on your local machine, you can store up to 2000 cache entries before the eviction kicks in.